# How to perform a join operation for following table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here is the database structure:

[image: database structure]

How can I find these columns: userId, firstName, lastName, path, file, type, content, size?

I am trying this query now, but it's not working.

```
SELECT t.userId, t.firstName, t.lastName, p.postId, p.content, p.file, p.type, p.path FROM tbl_users t JOIN post p ON p.userId = t.userId where t.userId = 'er.sharmauttam@gmail.com5a51e9ed426f8';
```

Comment: Add your php code to the question please.

Comment: Any error you are getting while running this query?
As per query you have posted you forgot to add comma between ``t.lastName`` and ``p.postId`` and also between ``p.type`` and ``p.path`` make sure there is no syntax error in your SQL query

Comment: You're missing some commas: `t.lastName p.postId` should be `t.lastName, p.postId` and `p.type p.path` should be `p.type, p.path`. Your query looks good just some typographical errors.

Comment: Add an example, sample data and expected result.

Comment: @cdaiga answer updated . can you please write query for this solution?

Comment: you can take column name as a sample data ;) and now i want userId, firstName, lastName, path, file, type, content. @cdaiga

Comment: @DevangNaghera answer updated . please check it again

Comment: @P.Salmon answer updated please check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is a table called tbl_users and post and both of them have userId
then this query should help you.and i hope $userId is a variable/parameter

```
    'SELECT t.userId, t.firstName, t.lastName, p.postId, 
p.content, p.file, p.type, p.path FROM tbl_users t 
INNER JOIN post p ON p.userId = t.userId where t.userId = ' . $userId;
```

Comment: Your're missing some commas in your query. See my comment in the question.

Comment: i am not missing anything?? @cdaiga

Comment: yes $userId is variable . but this query is not working .

Comment: hahahaha funny i guess u the one who have down voted my answer but its correct i fail to understand why u do that @cdaiga

Comment: @uttamsharma do u want to inner join the two tables?? that query should work perfectly well

Comment: Yes @MarvinCollins, I down voted because your answer is not correct. See my comment in the question.

Comment: yes . @MarvinCollins i want to retrieve these given fields . i dont know much about joins . i have given the data structure in images please check it which type of join will suitable . thanks for your efforts .

Comment: @cdaiga check answer again . i updated my answer . thanks for point out.

Comment: There you go, I changed my mind :) . Happy new year @MarvinCollins

Comment: thanks for the insight @cdaiga i have updated the answer it is supposed to work now

Comment: hahaha nice one @cdaiga thanks happy new year

Comment: happy new year guys . best experience ever on stackexchange .

Comment: now can you please solve my problem ? ;)

Comment: it solved what else do u need??

Comment: yes worked now . thank you very much bro